# What is the best text-mode web browser?

Tags: command-line, terminal, software-rec, browser

I'm looking for one that is frequently updated and full-featured.

Comment: [Per FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), avoid questions underlying subjective answers.

Comment: Produced in 1992, stable (Libwww) since 1997 and updated all years including 2016, 2017... **[`lynx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))**, reliable, most cited... the best.

Comment: there is also new browser [browsh](https://www.brow.sh/) that renders images and process JavaScript.

Comment: I prefer Browsh https://www.brow.sh/

Comment: // , Would you be willing to post this in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com ?  It looks like no one has asked this yet: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+the+best+text-mode+browser%3F

Comment: @NathanBasanese I found one there already that might be useful https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11678/text-based-browser-that-runs-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are many text web browsers, as there are many graphical web browsers, so it really depends on what you're looking for. [`lynx`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/) is a common slim choice, [`Elinks`](http://www.elinks.cz/) has many features. Both of these support other protocols, such as `ftp` and `gopher` (`Elinks` even supports `bittorrent`). `Elinks` may also be built with support for JavaScript, using Mozilla's former JavaScript implementation, Spidermonkey.

There is also [`w3m`](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/), which can also be used through `Emacs`.

If you want to try one at random, Wikipedia has a [list of text based browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser).

How to install these has more to do with how your distribution manages packages than with the browsers themselves. Some of them are probably in the package repositories for your distribution.

Answer (score 56):

As of November 2015, the actively maintained browsers are `links` and `lynx`. Many of the changes in both relate to TLS and security.  Here is the current state of progress:

- [links](http://links.twibright.com/) - 2.12 - *2015*. ([Changelog](http://links.twibright.com/download/ChangeLog))
- [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/) - unstable 2.8.9dev - *2015*, stable 2.8.8 - *2014*. ([Changelog](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html))
- [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) - unstable 0.12pre6 - *2012*, stable 0.11.7 - *2009*. ([Changelog](http://elinks.or.cz/news.html))
- [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) - 0.5.3 - *2011*, 0.5.2 - *2007*

Comment: I did not find your first line clear, so edited it, trying to improve it. Please verify.

Comment: Elinks had an unstable release shortly after this post was made. Unfortunately for me, that was three years ago! Links seems to have had an update in December 2014, and lynx had a development release in March 2014. My favorite of the three, w3m, is still without any type of release for four years.

Comment: I tried lynx, w3m and elinks.  My vote is for elinks.

Comment: Well, I am currently running w3m/0.5.3+git2016041. Which has a notably fix for 32-bit true color images support which makes it work better in vte based terminals for instance.

Comment: @AlMehdi Where did you get this version from?

Comment: In case anyone comes across this later, w3m's original version on Sourceforge was abandoned in 2011, but the version shipped in Debian and Ubuntu is the fork at https://github.com/tats/w3m, which is still patched regularly.

Answer (score 11):

I like links2, but primarily because it has a cool, lightweight 'graphical' mode. It's similar to just plain 'links', but you can invoke it with -g to get a display that renders images. It's very easily X-forwardable, too. But, when you don't want the HTML image rendering, it works just fine in the native ncurses interface as well.

Comment: Links and Links2 are (at least on Debian) the same program. The difference is that Links was compiled without support for graphical mode.